# Не могу обойти шаблон в поле ввода

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Приветствую.
Есть форма для заполнения анкеты. В поле ввода ящика есть шаблон___@__._
тест вводит ящик или перед шаблоном или после. Вот код:

```
WebElement imail = WebDriverFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=-section-form__email\"]"));
           imail.sendKeys("wert111@ro.ru");
```

[image: вот скрин]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Есть идеи?

Comment: Нужно смотреть логику обработчика на данном поле. Можно попробовать вводить емэил по частям и жадть немного между вводами. Еще вариант через цепочку действий реализовать - отдельно нажатие и релиз каждого символа.

Comment: @suit Спасибо за ответ. Пробовал. И координаты нажатия задавал, потом пообщались с devами и они выпилили этот шаблон. Так что оптимальное решение не найденно, но вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Даже ввод по одному символу со `sleep(0.5)` между ними не помогает?)